# Descend cols with rownames within nests

Tags: r

I have a nest of tables whereby I want to convert the rowname into the row cells that its in and order each column accordingly by the rank before its replaced by the rowname.

For example:

```
mtX <- apply(mtcars, 2, as.numeric) %>% data.frame(.)
rownames(mtX) <- rownames(mtcars)

mtNest <- mtX %>% nest_by(vs) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                      nest(data = -am) %>%
                      mutate(data = map(
                        data, ~ .x %>%
                          nest(data = -gear) %>% mutate(data = map(
                            data, ~ .x %>%  mutate(across(., function(x)
                              min_rank(-x))) %>% rownames(data)[order(-.x)]
                          ))
                      ))))
```

This is similar to my previous post: [Descend each column and update with row names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74048116/descend-each-column-and-update-with-row-names)

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `data = map(...)`.
> Caused by error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `data = map(...)`.
> Caused by error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `data = map(...)`.
> Caused by error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = across(., function(x) min_rank(-x))`.
> Caused by error in `across()`:
> ! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> ✖ Subscript has the wrong type `tbl_df<
> mpg : double
> cyl : double
> disp: double
> hp  : double
> drat: double
> wt  : double
> qsec: double
> carb: double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tibble/data.table`, it wouldn't allow row.names other than the index.  Thus, when we apply modifications on the dataset, it automatically replaces the row names with index when a function returns a tibble (here `nest` returns a tibble).  Therefore, it is better to create a row names column (`rownames_to_column` from `tibble`) before doing the nesting. Based on the code, we are recursively creating nested data.  In the innermost nested 'data', we loop over the columns that are `numeric`, get the rank and replace with the 'rn' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
out <- mtX %>% 
  rownames_to_column("rn") %>%
  nest_by(vs) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                      nest(data = -am) %>%
                      mutate(data = map(
                        data, ~ .x %>%
                          nest(data = -gear) %>% 
   mutate(data = map(
                            data, ~ .x %>% 
       mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x) rn[min_rank(-x)]))   ))))))
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     0 <tibble [2 × 2]>
2     1 <tibble [2 × 2]>

> out$data[[1]]$data[[1]]$data
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  rn            mpg       cyl       disp      hp        drat      wt            qsec          carb     
  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         <chr>    
1 Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Mazda RX4 Wag Mazda RX4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  rn             mpg            cyl           disp           hp             drat           wt             qsec           carb          
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
1 Porsche 914-2  Porsche 914-2  Maserati Bora Maserati Bora  Maserati Bora  Porsche 914-2  Maserati Bora  Porsche 914-2  Maserati Bora 
2 Ford Pantera L Ferrari Dino   Porsche 914-2 Porsche 914-2  Ford Pantera L Ford Pantera L Ford Pantera L Maserati Bora  Ferrari Dino  
3 Ferrari Dino   Ford Pantera L Ferrari Dino  Ferrari Dino   Ferrari Dino   Ferrari Dino   Ferrari Dino   Ford Pantera L Ford Pantera L
4 Maserati Bora  Maserati Bora  Porsche 914-2 Ford Pantera L Porsche 914-2  Maserati Bora  Porsche 914-2  Ferrari Dino   Porsche 914-2
```

Comment: Really good explanation, I will keep this in mind for similar scenarios. Thank you Akrun!